# Effects of Negative padding

Tags: android, view, padding

I'm just starting to learn android and i had a question regarding negative padding. How exactly does negative padding affect the view ?

Also, say I introduce a `bottomPadding` of "-5dp". Does this extend of the boundary of the padding by 5dp ?

All help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` after setting negative padding you will notice movement of the content into opposite direction - for example if you set `paddingLeft` to -5dp, it will be moved to the left side by 5dp, whereas setting it to 5dp would cause content to be moved into right position.