# what does "android:padding=-5dp" mean?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I'm inspecting some old android layout:

and i see this attribute in a customView

`android:padding="-5dp"`

what does this mean?

(a) when coming alone?

(b) when `android:paddingTop="-5dp"` comes after `android:padding="10dp"`
does this mean all paddings are 10 and the top is 5dp ?

**attention**

please note I'm asking specifically about negative value, not padding in general

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between px, dp, dip and sp in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: no, please note I'm asking specifically about negative value, not padding in general

Comment: It means what it says. offsetting the top of the page by a negative amount from the top of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) I think these two links will help you: [Effects of Negative padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312875/effects-of-negative-padding) and [Is it a bad practice to use negative margins in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android)

b) You are right, all paddings are set to 10dp first, then padding-top is set to -5dp. You "overwrite" the 10dp with the -5dp.

Answer (score -1):

Padding is the space between the view border and the content inside the view. when you say padding , it means padding in all directions (Top, left, bottom and right). when you say paddingTop , means padding only from the top.

Comment: please note I'm asking specifically about negative value, not padding in general